SQL query to audit employee claim based on specific sequence of rows defined by criteria
I need to create an exception/audit report for our accounting section.
The business case is an employee is deployed to remote location and can claim lodging cost if they are away from their family. If their family has moved to their work location/area then the claim is terminated (not part of this query).
The maximum period they can claim is 48 months. There can be a break of up to 6 months (the count of months doesn’t change during a break). If the person exceeds 6 months of break the month counter reset to zero and the employee is not eligible to claim. If the break is 6 months or less the count of remote work continues.
In the sample data below employee ID 49 worked at a remote location from 2019-04-01 until 2020-07-30 with a 5-month break. Then he worked at a different location from 2022-07-31 till 2023-06-30.
Sample data for employe 376. Has worked at the remote location from 2020-08-01 to 2024-11-30.  In the case a new file was started dated 2023-09-15. There was two claims for the month of 2023-10-01; the Repeat column indicate this.
Now, I can pull all the costing rows from the database to the app server, 205K rows and calculate the running sequence using a for loop but that has an impact on traffic (database is in a different city) and it increase processing on the IIS server. I want to be able to send a proper query to the database (Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP3-GDR) (KB5021129) - 13.0.6430.49 (X64)   Jan 22 2023 17:38:22   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: )) and have the app handle the request and presentation only.
This exception or audit report I need to create must show the members that are approaching or have exceeded the 48 months limit. I’ve been playing with windowed rowset and it works if there is no gaps. But where there are gaps of six months or less the report doesn't give what is expected.
The current query is using TotalMonths as parameter but it gives me wrong results. If I use 40 months as the criteria employee 049 should not show. If I use 10 months as the criteria employee 049 should show, and not just the row where (expected) Months = 10 but all the rows for this employee.
To summarize the business rules

Employe can claim up to 48 months of expenses when working remotely away from family

Employe can take a break of up to six month. The month counter for
the claim pauses and resume after the break.

If employee takes a break the month counter reset to zero.

If there is two claims for a month the partial days are checks. Claim
is denied if PartialDays exceed the number of days for the month.

When an employee exceed the parameter given all the rows for that employee must be part of the report.

Claims where there is a duplicate month must also be flagged.


The only other alternative I haven't tried is using a cursor; and I'm not familiar with that. Is there a way to do this with one SQL statement?
Table structure
-- table structure
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ir_Costs](
    [EID] [varchar](9) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [CLMinitialDT] [date] NOT NULL,
    [MonthYear] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Lodging] [smallmoney] NULL,
    [others] [smallmoney] NULL,
    [DaysPartial] [tinyint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ir_Costs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EID] ASC,
    [CLMinitialDT] ASC,
    [MonthYear] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

The query
The application code filters the input request and creates an ADODB command object. For our example the parameter would be @months = 40
DECLARE @months smallint=? -- the normal value for ? can be 48 +/-

SELECT Q1.* FROM 
( SELECT c.EID
    ,c.CLMinitialDT
    ,c.MonthYear
    ,LAG(c.MonthYear) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EID ORDER BY c.MonthYear ) as PrevMth
    ,c.Lodging 
    ,(SELECT SUM(Lodging + others) 
      FROM ir_Costs d 
      WHERE d.MonthYear <= c.MonthYear 
        and d.EID=c.EID and d.CLMinitialDT=c.CLMinitialDT 
      GROUP BY d.EID, d.CLMinitialDT
      ) AS RunningTotal 
    ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EID, c.MonthYear)-1 AS Repeats1
    ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EID) AS CostRows 
    ,NTILE(250) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EID ORDER BY c.monthyear,c.CLMinitialDT ) AS RowSeq
    ,datediff(MONTH
             ,LAG(c.MonthYear) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EID ORDER BY c.MonthYear )
             ,c.MonthYear )  as MonthGap
    ,datediff(MONTH, MIN(c.MonthYear) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EID )
             ,MAX(c.MonthYear) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EID )) + 1 as TotalMonths 
    ,c.DaysPartial
  FROM ir_Costs c 
) Q1  
WHERE (TotalMonths >= @months OR @months IS NULL)
ORDER BY EID, MonthYear

I also tried this with the same result
DECLARE @months smallint=48;
WITH Q1 AS ( SELECT c.EID
    ,c.CLMinitialDT 
    ,c.MonthYear
    ,LAG(c.MonthYear) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EID ORDER BY c.MonthYear ) as PrevMonth
    ,c.Lodging
    ,(SELECT SUM(Lodging + others) 
      FROM ir_Costs d 
      WHERE d.MonthYear <= c.MonthYear 
         and d.EID=c.EID and d.CLMinitialDT =c.CLMinitialDT  
      GROUP BY d.EID, d.CLMinitialDT 
      ) AS RunningTotal 
    ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EID, c.MonthYear)-1 AS Repeats1
    ,NTILE(250) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EID ORDER BY c.monthyear,c.CLMinitialDT  ) AS RowSeq
    ,datediff(MONTH, LAG(c.MonthYear) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EID ORDER BY c.MonthYear )
                   ,c.MonthYear )  as MonthGap
    --,datediff(MONTH, MIN(c.MonthYear) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EID )
      --             ,MAX(c.MonthYear) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EID )) + 1 as TotalMonths 
     ,c.DaysPartial
  FROM ir_Costs c 
)
SELECT Q1.*,(COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Q1.EID)) AS CostRows, max(RowSeq) as TotalMonths 
FROM Q1 
GROUP BY EID,CLMinitialDT,MonthYear,PrevMonth,Lodging,RunningTotal,Repeats1,RowSeq,MonthGap,DaysPartial
ORDER BY EID, MonthYear

I've rerun the simulation in https://dbfiddle.uk/CRlw1sni
Source Data



EID
CLMinitialDT
MonthYear
Accomodation
Others
DaysPartial




049
2018-07-03
2019-04-01
435.98
0.00
30


049
2018-07-03
2019-05-01
435.98
0.00
30


049
2018-07-03
2019-06-01
435.98
0.00
30


049
2018-07-03
2019-07-01
130.79
0.00
9


049
2018-07-03
2020-01-01
261.59
0.00
18


049
2018-07-03
2020-02-01
435.98
0.00
28


049
2018-07-03
2020-03-01
435.98
0.00
30


049
2018-07-03
2020-04-01
435.98
0.00
30


049
2018-07-03
2020-05-01
435.98
0.00
30


049
2018-07-03
2020-06-01
435.98
0.00
30


049
2018-07-03
2020-07-01
421.45
0.00
29


049
2021-05-21
2022-08-01
53.60
0.00
4


049
2021-05-21
2022-12-01
77.58
0.00
16


049
2021-05-21
2023-01-01
415.46
0.00
30


049
2021-05-21
2023-02-01
415.46
0.00
28


049
2021-05-21
2023-03-01
415.46
0.00
30


049
2021-05-21
2023-04-01
415.46
0.00
30


049
2021-05-21
2023-05-01
415.46
0.00
30


049
2021-05-21
2023-06-01
439.97
0.00
30


049
2021-05-21
2023-07-01
263.98
0.00
18


376
2019-08-01
2020-08-01
1500.00
100.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2020-09-01
1500.00
0.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2020-10-01
1500.00
0.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2020-11-01
1500.00
0.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2020-12-01
1500.00
100.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2021-01-01
1500.00
0.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2021-02-01
1500.00
100.00
28


376
2019-08-01
2021-03-01
1500.00
0.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2021-04-01
1500.00
100.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2021-05-01
1500.00
0.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2021-06-01
1500.00
100.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2021-07-01
1500.00
100.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2021-08-01
1500.00
100.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2021-09-01
1500.00
100.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2021-10-01
1500.00
100.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2021-11-01
1500.00
100.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2021-12-01
1500.00
0.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2022-01-01
22.00
0.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2022-02-01
1522.00
0.00
28


376
2019-08-01
2022-03-01
1522.00
0.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2022-04-01
1522.00
0.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2022-05-01
1522.00
0.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2022-06-01
1522.00
0.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2022-07-01
1522.00
0.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2022-08-01
1522.00
0.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2022-09-01
1522.00
0.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2022-10-01
1522.00
0.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2022-11-01
1522.00
0.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2022-12-01
1522.00
0.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2023-01-01
1522.00
0.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2023-02-01
1522.00
0.00
28


376
2019-08-01
2023-03-01
1522.00
0.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2023-04-01
1552.00
0.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2023-05-01
1552.00
0.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2023-06-01
1552.00
0.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2023-07-01
1552.00
0.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2023-08-01
1552.00
0.00
30


376
2019-08-01
2023-10-01
1600.00
0.00
30


376
2023-09-15
2023-09-01
1600.00
0.00
30


376
2023-09-15
2023-10-01
1600.00
0.00
30


376
2023-09-15
2023-11-01
1600.00
0.00
30


376
2023-09-15
2023-12-01
1600.00
0.00
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-01-01
1600.00
0.00
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-02-01
1600.00
0.00
28


376
2023-09-15
2024-03-01
1600.00
0.00
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-04-01
1600.00
112.20
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-05-01
1600.00
0.00
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-06-01
1600.00
119.89
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-07-01
1600.00
0.00
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-08-01
1680.00
216.85
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-09-01
1780.00
0.00
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-10-01
1969.00
0.00
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-11-01
1680.00
210.53
30



Example (with a break)  In Aug 2020 the employee returned home for two year. The RowSeq must return to zero.



EID
CLMinitialDT
MonthYear
PreviousMonth
Lodging
RunningTotal
Repeats
CostRows
RowSeq
MonthGap
TotalMonths
DaysPartial




49
2018-07-03
2019-04-01
NULL
435.98
435.98
0
20
1
NULL
52
30


49
2018-07-03
2019-05-01
2019-04-01
435.98
871.96
0
20
2
1
52
30


49
2018-07-03
2019-06-01
2019-05-01
435.98
1307.94
0
20
3
1
52
30


49
2018-07-03
2019-07-01
2019-06-01
130.79
1438.73
0
20
4
1
52
9


49
2018-07-03
2020-01-01
2019-07-01
261.59
1700.32
0
20
5
6
52
18


49
2018-07-03
2020-02-01
2020-01-01
435.98
2136.3
0
20
6
1
52
28


49
2018-07-03
2020-03-01
2020-02-01
435.98
2572.28
0
20
7
1
52
30


49
2018-07-03
2020-04-01
2020-03-01
435.98
3008.26
0
20
8
1
52
30


49
2018-07-03
2020-05-01
2020-04-01
435.98
3444.24
0
20
9
1
52
30


49
2018-07-03
2020-06-01
2020-05-01
435.98
3880.22
0
20
10
1
52
30


49
2018-07-03
2020-07-01
2020-06-01
421.45
4301.67
0
20
11
1
52
29


49
2021-05-21
2022-08-01
2020-07-01
53.6
4355.27
0
20
12
25
52
4


49
2021-05-21
2022-12-01
2022-08-01
77.58
4432.85
0
20
13
4
52
16


49
2021-05-21
2023-01-01
2022-12-01
415.46
4848.31
0
20
14
1
52
30


49
2021-05-21
2023-02-01
2023-01-01
415.46
5263.77
0
20
15
1
52
28


49
2021-05-21
2023-03-01
2023-02-01
415.46
5679.23
0
20
16
1
52
30


49
2021-05-21
2023-04-01
2023-03-01
415.46
6094.69
0
20
17
1
52
30


49
2021-05-21
2023-05-01
2023-04-01
415.46
6510.15
0
20
18
1
52
30


49
2021-05-21
2023-06-01
2023-05-01
439.97
6950.12
0
20
19
1
52
30


49
2021-05-21
2023-07-01
2023-06-01
263.98
7214.1
0
20
20
1
52
18



EXPECTED  Here we want the row sequence RowSeq to return to zero after a gap greater than six months.



EID
CLMinitialDT
MonthYear
PreviousMonth
Lodging
RunningTotal
Repeats
CostRows
RowSeq
MonthGap
TotalMonths
DaysPartial




49
2018-07-03
2019-04-01
NULL
435.98
435.98
0
20
0
NULL
10
30


49
2018-07-03
2019-05-01
2019-04-01
435.98
871.96
0
20
1
1
10
30


49
2018-07-03
2019-06-01
2019-05-01
435.98
1307.94
0
20
2
1
10
30


49
2018-07-03
2019-07-01
2019-06-01
130.79
1438.73
0
20
3
1
10
9


49
2018-07-03
2020-01-01
2019-07-01
261.59
1700.32
0
20
4
6
10
18


49
2018-07-03
2020-02-01
2020-01-01
435.98
2136.3
0
20
5
1
10
28


49
2018-07-03
2020-03-01
2020-02-01
435.98
2572.28
0
20
6
1
10
30


49
2018-07-03
2020-04-01
2020-03-01
435.98
3008.26
0
20
7
1
10
30


49
2018-07-03
2020-05-01
2020-04-01
435.98
3444.24
0
20
8
1
10
30


49
2018-07-03
2020-06-01
2020-05-01
435.98
3880.22
0
20
9
1
10
30


49
2018-07-03
2020-07-01
2020-06-01
421.45
4301.67
0
20
10
1
10
29


49
2021-05-21
2022-08-01
2020-07-01
53.6
4355.27
0
20
0
25
10
4


49
2021-05-21
2022-12-01
2022-08-01
77.58
4432.85
0
20
1
4
10
16


49
2021-05-21
2023-01-01
2022-12-01
415.46
4848.31
0
20
2
1
10
30


49
2021-05-21
2023-02-01
2023-01-01
415.46
5263.77
0
20
3
1
10
28


49
2021-05-21
2023-03-01
2023-02-01
415.46
5679.23
0
20
4
1
10
30


49
2021-05-21
2023-04-01
2023-03-01
415.46
6094.69
0
20
5
1
10
30


49
2021-05-21
2023-05-01
2023-04-01
415.46
6510.15
0
20
6
1
10
30


49
2021-05-21
2023-06-01
2023-05-01
439.97
6950.12
0
20
7
1
10
30


49
2021-05-21
2023-07-01
2023-06-01
263.98
7214.1
0
20
8
1
10
18



Another employee (first 35 months skipped)
In this example the employe did not have a break/gap but there is a repeat claim for 2023-10-01 and it introduce an error in the running total; and CostRows > TotalMonths



EID
CLMinitialDT
MonthYear
PreviousMonth
Lodging
RunningTotal
Repeats
CostRows
RowSeq
MonthGap
TotalMonths
DaysPartial




376
2019-08-01
2023-07-01
2023-06-01
1552
54038
0
53
36
1
52
30


376
2019-08-01
2023-08-01
2023-07-01
1552
55590
0
53
37
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2023-09-01
2023-08-01
1600
1600
0
53
38
1
52
30


376
2019-08-01
2023-10-01
2023-10-01
1600
57190
1
53
39
0
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2023-10-01
2023-09-01
1600
3200
1
53
40
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2023-11-01
2023-10-01
1600
4800
0
53
41
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2023-12-01
2023-11-01
1600
6400
0
53
42
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-01-01
2023-12-01
1600
8000
0
53
43
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-02-01
2024-01-01
1600
9600
0
53
44
1
52
28


376
2023-09-15
2024-03-01
2024-02-01
1600
11200
0
53
45
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-04-01
2024-03-01
1600
12912.2
0
53
46
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-05-01
2024-04-01
1600
14512.2
0
53
47
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-06-01
2024-05-01
1600
16232.09
0
53
48
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-07-01
2024-06-01
1600
17832.09
0
53
49
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-08-01
2024-07-01
1680
19728.94
0
53
50
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-09-01
2024-08-01
1780
21508.94
0
53
51
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-10-01
2024-09-01
1969
23477.94
0
53
52
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-11-01
2024-10-01
1680
25368.47
0
53
53
1
52
30



EXPECTED  The Running Total should continue to add properly as there are no gaps in the sequence.



EID
CLMinitialDT
MonthYear
PreviousMonth
Lodging
RunningTotal
Repeats1
CostRows
RowSeq
MonthGap
TotalMonths
DaysPartial




376
2019-08-01
2023-07-01
2023-06-01
1552.00
54038.00
0
53
36
1
52
30


376
2019-08-01
2023-08-01
2023-07-01
1552.00
55590.00
0
53
37
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2023-09-01
2023-08-01
1600.00
1600.00
0
53
38
1
52
30


376
2019-08-01
2023-10-01
2023-10-01
1600.00
57190.00
1
53
39
0
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2023-10-01
2023-09-01
1600.00
3200.00
1
53
40
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2023-11-01
2023-10-01
1600.00
4800.00
0
53
41
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2023-12-01
2023-11-01
1600.00
6400.00
0
53
42
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-01-01
2023-12-01
1600.00
8000.00
0
53
43
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-02-01
2024-01-01
1600.00
9600.00
0
53
44
1
52
28


376
2023-09-15
2024-03-01
2024-02-01
1600.00
11200.00
0
53
45
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-04-01
2024-03-01
1600.00
12912.20
0
53
46
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-05-01
2024-04-01
1600.00
14512.20
0
53
47
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-06-01
2024-05-01
1600.00
16232.09
0
53
48
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-07-01
2024-06-01
1600.00
17832.09
0
53
49
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-08-01
2024-07-01
1680.00
19728.94
0
53
50
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-09-01
2024-08-01
1780.00
21508.94
0
53
51
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-10-01
2024-09-01
1969.00
23477.94
0
53
52
1
52
30


376
2023-09-15
2024-11-01
2024-10-01
1680.00
25368.47
0
53
53
1
52
30



SOLUTION
Thank you @ValNik for you help.  The final query is:
DECLARE @months smallint=48;
SELECT * 
FROM(
select *
  ,max(RunningMonth)over(partition by EID) maxRunningMonth
from(
select *
  ,count(case when isBreak=0 then coalesce(MonthGap,0) else 0 end)
      over(partition by EID,grN order by MonthYear) RunningMonth
  ,SUM(Lodging + coalesce(others,0.0)) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY EID,grN ORDER BY MonthYear) as RunningTotal
from(
select *
  ,sum(isBreak)
    over(partition by EID order by MonthYear) grN
from(
  SELECT c.EID
    ,c.CLMinitialDT
    ,c.MonthYear
    ,LAG(c.MonthYear) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EID ORDER BY c.MonthYear ) as PrevMth
    ,c.Lodging 
    ,c.others
  --  ,SUM(Lodging + coalesce(others,0.0)) over(partition by EId,CLMinitialDt order by MonthYear) RunningTotal
    ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EID, c.MonthYear)-1 AS Repeats1
    ,datediff(MONTH, LAG(c.MonthYear) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EID ORDER BY c.MonthYear )
                   ,c.MonthYear )  as MonthGap
    ,case when datediff(MONTH, LAG(c.MonthYear) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EID ORDER BY c.MonthYear )
                   ,c.MonthYear )>6 then 1 
     else 0 end isBreak
    ,datediff(MONTH, MIN(c.MonthYear) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EID )
                   ,MAX(c.MonthYear) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EID )) + 1 as TotalMonths 
  FROM ir_Costs c 
)a
)b
)c
)d WHERE (maxRunningMonth >= @months OR @months IS NULL)

Can be viewed here https://dbfiddle.uk/TrKMACHd

Please do not post images of data try to create it in a temp table or something that other people can test/use.  See here:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Provide source table structure and test data.

Just to clarify, the Expected column is what I want to read in the RowSeq column, and the TotalMonths should have the maximum value of the Expected column. That will be used to filter the report for people exceeding X months in the sequence.

You need to show the desired result instead of the result of your current query, i.e. what you would like to get. The purpose of the Days Partial column is also unclear. Explain or remove from the example as superfluous. You can also exclude the columns Accommodation Type CD, Rom cd from the example. Their purpose is not clear and is not necessary for the task.

In your example, for (EmplId,CLMinitialDT) (49,'2018-07-03') 48(52) months are not achieved, because the calculation starts again after a gap of 25 months. Are these rows needed in the output result? Add an example of the data so that you can see what is expected as a result when the duration approaches 48(52) months. Also see an example of dividing (gaps and islands) into parts that can be considered separately (https://dbfiddle.uk/y3_0BQ1a).

Thank you @ValNik but the RunningMonths must also pause when there is a valid break (<=6 months). This is to indicate how many months were claimed.
Updated simulation: https://dbfiddle.uk/CRlw1sni

Do you consider (376,2023-09-15) and (376, 2019-08-01) as one claim or different? (https://dbfiddle.uk/sc8Rg53T)

Yes, should be case when isBreak=0 then coalesce(MonthGap,0) else 0 end. Also added column maxRunningMonth. Corrected example (dbfiddle.uk/NJHSgKou). You can use WHERE (maxRunningMonth >= @months OR @months IS NULL) to retrieve only groups, where this condition was occur.

In real life  (376,2023-09-15) and (376, 2019-08-01)  were submitted as two different claim (escaping initial checks) but technically they are one as there is no gaps.
You solution led me to my final solution. Thank you so much.
I think I got it: https://dbfiddle.uk/1TKp3Ml5

Thank you @ValNik for you help. The final query is:
DECLARE @months smallint=?; -- where ? is the number of months of continuous claim (with allowed gaps of 6 months) 
SELECT * 
FROM(
select *
  ,max(RunningMonth)over(partition by EID) maxRunningMonth
from(
select *
  ,count(case when isBreak=0 then coalesce(MonthGap,0) else 0 end)
      over(partition by EID,grN order by MonthYear) RunningMonth
  ,SUM(Lodging + coalesce(others,0.0)) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY EID,grN ORDER BY MonthYear) as RunningTotal
from(
select *
  ,sum(isBreak)
    over(partition by EID order by MonthYear) grN
from(
  SELECT c.EID
    ,c.CLMinitialDT
    ,c.MonthYear
    ,LAG(c.MonthYear) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EID ORDER BY c.MonthYear ) as PrevMth
    ,c.Lodging 
    ,c.others
  --  ,SUM(Lodging + coalesce(others,0.0)) over(partition by EId,CLMinitialDt order by MonthYear) RunningTotal
    ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EID, c.MonthYear)-1 AS Repeats1
    ,datediff(MONTH, LAG(c.MonthYear) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EID ORDER BY c.MonthYear )
                   ,c.MonthYear )  as MonthGap
    ,case when datediff(MONTH, LAG(c.MonthYear) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EID ORDER BY c.MonthYear )
                   ,c.MonthYear )>6 then 1 
     else 0 end isBreak
    ,datediff(MONTH, MIN(c.MonthYear) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EID )
                   ,MAX(c.MonthYear) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EID )) + 1 as TotalMonths 
  FROM ir_Costs c 
)a
)b
)c
)d WHERE (maxRunningMonth >= @months OR @months IS NULL)

Can be viewed here https://dbfiddle.uk/TrKMACHd

Good luck in programming!
